# Camera blinks but doesn't record

Tags: boot, camera, streaming-video

I am trying to start a stream on my Raspberry Pi Camera when I boot the Raspberry Pi. I have tried the following options:

1. Using crontab

   @reboot /home/pi/video.sh &
2. Using init.d
   Copied the script video.sh into init.d
3. Added following code to /etc/rc.local

   if [ $(tty) == /dev/tty1 ]; then

   /home/pi/video.sh &

   fi

I can also add that the script contain this:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 640 -h 360 -fps 25 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554}' :demux=h264
```

This string starts a continuous flow of data and start to stream from VLC. To watch the stream I start VLC, or as I do, start the HTML page I have created and enter the raspberry IP-address.

My guess is that when booting the Pi it runs the script, but after that stop or get terminated by another startup script, since the camera just blinks for a second then turn off.

Is there a way to make this script keep running even after startup?

Comment: Does your script work normal in commandline mode? As user `root` and as user `pi`?

Comment: It does work in commandline. Only as Pi thought, somethind about VLC can't be run as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now solved it.

My solution was to make a script the check if there are any processes named vlc, and if there are none it run the script that starts the stream. Then I added the followin to cron with crontab -e:

```
@reboot /home/pi/check.sh
```

The script itself contain the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
pidof='pidof vlc'
if [[ -z $pidof ]]
then
        exit
else
        /home/pi/video.sh
fi
exit
```

video.sh contain the following string to start the stream:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 640 -h 360 -fps 25 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554}' :demux=h264 &
```

What I think may cause the problem I had was that when the Pi run scripts at startup, it just runs it, and when finnished it stop. That would explain why the camera blinked for about 1 second and then stopped.

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved this! If you could mark this self-answer (this one) as answer, that would be great. We are trying to get the site Q:A ratio up and doing this would help us a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Marked as answered. I had to wait 24 hours to do so after answering and forgot about this this weekend.

Comment: Of course. No probleema, and again, glad to here that it got resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Anything in /etc/rc.local should keep running after boot indefinitely. If it is crashing, you can make it restart automatically by putting it in a while loop:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 640 -h 360 -fps 25 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554}' :demux=h264
done
```

Comment: Same result as with everything else. The Camera LED blink for a second, then nothing.

Comment: I'd suggest then trying to break down the command. The fact that it flashes suggests the program is crashing. If you run only the raspivid portion (before the |), does it still happen?

Answer (score 0):

Most bootscripts run as `root`.
VLC doesn't allow that.
You should run vlc as normal user, maybe like so:

`raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 640 -h 360 -fps 25 |`**`su pi -c "`**`cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554}' :demux=h264`**`"`**

or in `/etc/crontab`:

`@reboot`**`pi`**`/home/pi/video.sh &`

or in the `/etc/rc.local`:

`if [ $(tty) == /dev/tty1 ]; then`
**`su pi -c "`**`/home/pi/video.sh`**`"`**`&
fi`